# vscode: No autocomplete for `f.Close()` on *File

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

Is there a reason, why vscode does not suggest to use `f.Close()`?

[image: f.Cl... no autocomplete]

I have gopls installed, and yesterday autocomplete worked fine

Restarting vscode did not help.

Comment: Do you have gpls installed? Proper module setup?

Comment: @Volker I updated the question: I have gopls installed, and yesterday autocomplete worked fine

Comment: try to restart language server. "Go: Restart Language Server"

Comment: @ManjeetThakur restarting the language server did not help. But I found the solution. See below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem:

Above code belongs to the module "read-bytes".

I opened the file from within a different module.

Even restarting vscode did not help.

To solve this, I used "File / Open Folder", and opened the folder of "read-bytes".

Now autocomplete works fine.

Related: [Single-folder workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_singlefolder-workspaces)